# Creating an index page of empy divs only (no display, even after defining height/width)

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to create an index page that displays three rows of 7 squares. It sounds lame, but I have some jQuery ideas I think will eventually make it look pretty cool. I thought creating empty divs for the squares would do the trick and would allow me to simply define the sizes (heights and widths) of all the divs. Problem: can't get them to display.

I read lots of other questions about this problem, but the fix was always to define a width for the div, but this hasn't worked for me. I also looked into setting this up as a table, since that's basically what I want it to look like, but MDN shows  as "not recommended for layout," and I'd like to write code that's up to snuff.

I compared my code to some of the code I saw in a jQuery lesson in codecademy, and I can't see any real difference that would cause the codecademy code to display squares and mine to display nothing. Any help or suggestions about how to address this problem and get my vision to render on the page would be great! Thanks.

Here's the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<container class="row">
    <div class="sqtop"></div>
    <div class="sqtop"></div>
    <div class="sqtop"></div>
    <div class="sqtop"></div>
    <div class="sqtop"></div>
    <div class="sqtop"></div>
    <div class="sqtop"></div>
</container>
<container class="row">
    <div class="sqmid"></div>
    <div class="sqmid"></div>
    <div class="sqmid"></div>
    <div class="sqmid"></div>
    <div class="sqmid"></div>
    <div class="sqmid"></div>
    <div class="sqmid"></div>
</container>
<container class="row">
    <div class="sqbtm"></div>
    <div class="sqbtm"></div>
    <div class="sqbtm"></div>
    <div class="sqbtm"></div>
    <div class="sqbtm"></div>
    <div class="sqbtm"></div>
    <div class="sqbtm"></div>   
</container>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
background-color: gray;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.row {
width: 600px;
height: 100px;
padding: 1em;
text-align: center;
}
.sqtop {
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
min-height: 10px;
min-width: 10px;
color: black;
background-color: yellow;
border-radius: 5px;
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your absolute positioning is messing with the layout. Basically since all of the divs have an absolute position, they all show atop of each other.

Another problem is that you're only styling one of the rows, while the other two have no CSS attributes attached to them.

Here is a fix for the CSS:

> body { 
>     background-color: gray; height: 100%; width: 100%; } 
>   .row {
>     width: 600px; height: 100px; padding: 1em; text-align: center; }
>   .sqtop, .sqmid, .sqbtm { 
>     height: 20px; width: 20px; min-height: 10px;
>     min-width: 10px; color: black; background-color: yellow; display:
>     inline-block; border-radius: 5px; vertical-align: middle; }

This doesn't solve all of the problems though. The boxes still need to be in rows. Since the div's dont know exactly where where a line break should be, you can add a div that will create a line break in the HTML. This is how it would look like:

```
<container class="row">
    <div class="sqtop"></div>
    <div class="sqtop"></div>
    <div class="sqtop"></div>
    <div class="sqtop"></div>
    <div class="sqtop"></div>
    <div class="sqtop"></div>
    <div class="sqtop"></div>
</container>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<container class="row">
    <div class="sqmid"></div>
    <div class="sqmid"></div>
    <div class="sqmid"></div>
    <div class="sqmid"></div>
    <div class="sqmid"></div>
    <div class="sqmid"></div>
    <div class="sqmid"></div>
</container>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<container class="row">
    <div class="sqbtm"></div>
    <div class="sqbtm"></div>
    <div class="sqbtm"></div>
    <div class="sqbtm"></div>
    <div class="sqbtm"></div>
    <div class="sqbtm"></div>
    <div class="sqbtm"></div>   
</container>
```

That should give you 3 rows with 7 divs.

Answer (score 0):

remove absolute position, http://jsfiddle.net/ZG7jZ/

```
.sqtop {
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   min-height: 10px;
   min-width: 10px;
   color: black;
   background-color: yellow;
   border-radius: 5px;
   /*position: absolute;*/
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I removed the absolute position from the CSS, but I'm still getting nothing on the display. The only thing that is showing up is my gray background, but no squares!

Comment: It works fine on the fiddle are you sure it's not something you have done in other parts of your CSS?

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks for all the help. There was something mysterious going on with the main.css file the html file was referencing. I had the file located at styles/main.css, but every now and again in finder, I would see the file was somehow back in the same part of the directory as the index.html file. Basically, the CSS fixes I was saving were saving to this file and only worked once I replaced the other file. Not sure why this was happening and whether Sublime Text or OS X is to blame.

Comment: Point being: thanks to all for the helpful replies. A lesson I keep learning: when the CSS isn't working out, look back at your HTML!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're only applying your styling to `sqtop`. Try this:

```
body {
background-color: gray;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.row {
padding: 1em;
text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.row>div {
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
color: black;
background-color: yellow;
border-radius: 5px;
vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/keurr/1/

Comment: Thanks. I only had the CSS applied to the sqtop class in order to get the format right. I added the other two (sqmid and sqbtm) but can't get anything to display.